# Does any force on a spring make it oscillate?

Tags: forces, energy, potential-energy, spring

If I push one end of a spring (while the other end is attached to a rigid support) with a force of F and over a distance of $x = F/k$, it is only after a the end of the spring has been displaced x that it pulls back with a the same for F. However, over that distance ($x$) I have done work $W = Fx$ on the spring, where as it has done much less work (only after $x$ will it be pulling back with the same force). So not all energy the work I have done is stored as potential energy in the spring, some of it must be in some other form. If it is a frictionless system, does that mean the spring oscillates if I stop applying F after the distance $x$.

The answer to this question might be obvious for most, but I guess my reason for asking is that I have always pictured the spring to stop after it has elongated enough of a distance ($x$) that it can pull back with the same force.

Comment: @DavidWhite Why not post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force required to stretch a spring is $F=kx$, where it is seen that the stretching force increases as the spring stretches more.  To calculate the amount of work that this stretching takes, you must set up and solve the integral $W=\int Fdx = \int kx dx$, where the integral is evaluated between the limits of zero and the total stretch of the spring, in appropriate units (usually meters).  When this is done for a spring, it results in $W=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

As you are stretching the spring, you must provide the force that is doing the stretching.  According to Newton's 3rd law, the spring is putting an equal magnitude force on your hand whose direction is oppositely directed, which means that your hand must provide the exact amount of work that was required to stretch the spring.  That work will be stored in the spring as spring potential energy until the spring returns to its unstretched position.  This simply means that there is no "missing" work, and naturally, conservation of energy (aka work) continues to hold in this circumstance.

Comment: David. Nice answer 